# SceneKit: how to create chessboard pattern for SCNFloor from image?

Tags: scenekit, skscene, sceneview

The goal is to create an infinite chessboard pattern.

Using a SCNFloor and the attached image, we produce something close but not quite like a chessboard. Some black squares merge where they shouldn't.

We tried different values for `Scale`, `WrapS`, `WrapT`, `Min filter`, `Map filter`, and `Mip filter`. The screenshot shows the current values.

Is the underlying image not correct, or what setting do we need to change for the SCNFloor?

**Repeated image:**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: I tried your texture on an SCNFloor, and the squares looked regular, unlike your screenshot. Have you changed any other settings?

Comment: @JamesP nope. So you're saying your SCNFloor looks like a regular chessboard? Did you just use the default settings?

Comment: Yes, everything default, scale 1. It looks like you would expect. Your little preview sphere in the corner looks wrong too, the texture is offset, on mine it's centered.

Comment: @JamesP ok thanks so much. will try with a fresh project. btw do you have any advice for this q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42019638/scenekit-advice-on-reproducing-glowing-light-trail-like-with-tron-light-cycles?noredirect=1#comment71219248_42019638

Answer (score 0):

```
#import "GameViewController.h"

@interface GameViewController ()

@property (nonatomic) CGFloat chessBoardWidth;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat chessBoardDepth;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat tileWidth;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat tileDepth;
@property (nonatomic, getter=isOdd) BOOL odd;

@end

@implementation GameViewController

-(instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];

    if(self) {
        self.chessBoardWidth = 10.0f;
        self.chessBoardDepth = 10.0f;
        self.tileWidth = 1.0f;
        self.tileDepth = 1.0f;
    }

    return self;
}

-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    // create a new scene
    SCNScene *scene = [SCNScene sceneNamed:@"art.scnassets/chessboard.scn"];

    // create and add a camera to the scene
    SCNNode *cameraNode = [SCNNode node];
    cameraNode.camera = [SCNCamera camera];
    [scene.rootNode addChildNode:cameraNode];

    // place the camera
    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 150);

    // create and add a light to the scene
    SCNNode *lightNode = [SCNNode node];
    lightNode.light = [SCNLight light];
    lightNode.light.type = SCNLightTypeOmni;
    lightNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 10, 10);
    [scene.rootNode addChildNode:lightNode];

    // create and add an ambient light to the scene
    SCNNode *ambientLightNode = [SCNNode node];
    ambientLightNode.light = [SCNLight light];
    ambientLightNode.light.type = SCNLightTypeAmbient;
    ambientLightNode.light.color = [NSColor darkGrayColor];
    [scene.rootNode addChildNode:ambientLightNode];

    // Material

    SCNMaterial *blackMaterial = [SCNMaterial material];
    blackMaterial.diffuse.contents = [NSColor blackColor];

    SCNMaterial *whiteMaterial = [SCNMaterial material];
    whiteMaterial.diffuse.contents = [NSColor whiteColor];

    // Geometry

    SCNPlane *blackTile = [[SCNPlane alloc] init];
    blackTile.firstMaterial = blackMaterial;

    SCNPlane *whiteTile = [[SCNPlane alloc] init];
    whiteTile.firstMaterial = whiteMaterial;

    // Parent node

    SCNNode *parentNode = [[SCNNode alloc] init];
    [scene.rootNode addChildNode:parentNode];

    self.odd = YES;

    for (uint x=0; x < self.chessBoardWidth; x++) {
        for (uint z=0; z < self.chessBoardDepth; z++) {

            // Add tile

            SCNNode *tileNode = [[SCNNode alloc] init];

            if(self.isOdd) {
                tileNode.geometry = blackTile;
            } else {
                tileNode.geometry = whiteTile;
            }

            [parentNode addChildNode:tileNode];

            // Position tile
            tileNode.position = SCNVector3Make(self.tileWidth * x, 0, self.tileDepth * z);

            // Alternate

            if(self.isOdd) {
                self.odd = NO;
            } else {
                self.odd = YES;
            }
        }
    }

    // set the scene to the view
    self.gameView.scene = scene;

    // allows the user to manipulate the camera
    self.gameView.allowsCameraControl = YES;

    // show statistics such as fps and timing information
    self.gameView.showsStatistics = YES;

    // configure the view
    self.gameView.backgroundColor = [NSColor grayColor];
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks! But this will create an infinite board like a SCNFloor? Not clear what `chessBoardWidth` and `chessBoardDepth` are for if this is infinite? Wouldn't fixing these values, for instance, imply that if the camera moves past `chessBoardDepth` the chess board vanishes?

Comment: True, however, you can increase those values or the size of tiles and make sure it always covers for the viewing frustum of the camera. It doesn't have to be infinite.

Comment: Thanks Karl. Have you tried this approach and can vouch for it being performant? If not, I can test some, but I'm concerned this approach is not as performant as a SCNFloor.